# Wamp Server showing blank page for nested directory

Tags: php, wamp, wampserver

This link

> http://localhost/

works fine.
This link doesn't work

> http://localhost/shlingy/

directory location 
`C:\wamp\www\shlingy\index.html`

Does anybody know why this link does not work?

Comment: What's in the shlingy subdir?

Comment: What do you have in those directories?  What does "blank page" mean - an error, or literally a page with nothing on it?  If the latter, it sounds like you have an index page with no content ... or the text and background colors are the same.

Comment: Also check your apache error_logs.

Comment: yes page with nothing although it has index.html file

Comment: And what's in this index.html? If removing the index.html completely then gives you a 40x type error page, then everything's working fine and most likely your .html page is empty or so broken it can't be rendered.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether there is a `.htaccess` file in www or www/shlingy directory or not. If there is, rename or remove it. Probably a rewrite rule in that file is causing the problem.

Also, make a index.html file in the www/shlingy directory which will be displayed when you access the shlingy.

Answer (score 0):

It was a mistake on my end that i call a constructor of PHP file at the start page but that file contain an error. Its annoying that server just show blank page instead of error Massagining